# How to fix "exit status 1 " error when deploying on digital ocean

Tags: django, postgresql, digital-ocean, mysql-python, git-bash

I'm trying to deploy a django website on digital ocean. I was able to clone my project from GitHub to droplet on digital ocean. This web project I cloned has requirements[image].txt file. When I ran the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` in other to install all the packages in my project, the packages installed halfway and threw back an error message `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1` as found in the the attached photograph. Also, I used MySQL locally but I want to use postgrel on live server. I don't know why I'm getting the error message? I can't find where I made any mistake.

Comment: If you check the rest of the error message it says `OSError: mysql_config not found`. So you might want to check your database configs. Also, add the traceback as text in your question so it's easier to read/help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to fix the issue by removing MySQL client and pschopg2 from the requirements.txt fill before running the installations